# Failed to read post request in Spring Boot app (400)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I wrote simple CRUD Spring Boot app, but the POST endpoints don't work for some reason. I send the correct set of key-value pairs,
But I get the same error every time:

```
{
    "nickname": "bob",
    "kind": "cat",
    "birthday": "12.02.2020",
    "vetRecords": null
}

{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "detail": "Failed to read request",
    "instance": "/api/v1/users/4/animals"
}
```

I tried sending same request with debugger, but it doesn't stop in moment when I provide request. CommonsRequestLoggingFilter also shows only this:

```
2023-04-22T13:59:47.087+04:00 DEBUG 22330 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter      : Before request [POST /api/v1/users/4/animals]
2023-04-22T13:59:47.344+04:00 DEBUG 22330 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter      : REQUEST DATA: POST /api/v1/users/4/animals, payload=
{
    "nickname": "bob",
    "kind": "cat",
    "birthday": "12.02.2020",
    "vetRecords": null
}]
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("{id}/animals")
    public AnimalDto createAnimal(@PathVariable Long id,
                                  @Validated(OnCreate.class) @RequestBody AnimalDto animalDto) {
        Animal animal = animalMapper.toEntity(animalDto);
        Animal createdAnimal = animalService.create(animal, id);
        return animalMapper.toDto(createdAnimal);
    }
```

DTO:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AnimalDto {
    @NotNull(message = "Id must be not null", groups = OnUpdate.class)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull(message = "Animal name must not be null", groups = {OnUpdate.class, OnCreate.class})
    @Length(max = 256, message = "Animal name must be less than 256 symbols")
    private String nickname;

    @NotNull(message = "Animal kind must not be null", groups = {OnUpdate.class, OnCreate.class})
    @Length(max = 256, message = "Animal kind must be less than 256 symbols")
    private String kind;

    @NotNull(message = "Animal age must not be null", groups = {OnUpdate.class, OnCreate.class})
    private Date birthday;

    private List<VetRecord> vetRecords;
}
```

Entity:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Animal {

    private Long id;
    private String nickname;
    private String kind;
    private Date birthday;
    private List<VetRecord> vetRecords;
}
```

Mapper (MapStruct):

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface AnimalMapper {

    AnimalDto toDto(Animal animal);

    List<AnimalDto> toDto(List<Animal> animals);

    Animal toEntity(AnimalDto animalDto);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is an error in the birthday parameter you are trying to send. The format is not correct. It should be something like this:

```
{ 'nickname': 'bob', 'kind': 'cat', 'birthday': '2023-04-22T15:00:00Z' }
```

If you only want to store just the year, month, and day, please refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html.